# Call table-returning function on each row in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, postgis

I have a table with an unknown amount of rows, let's say

```
-----
geom
-----
0123
3216
6549
...
```

And a function that returns table:

```
> select * from myFunc('line(1 2, 3 4, 5 6)'::geometry);
----------
val1 val2
----------
10   98
75   65
```

So I want to call this function for each row in the table above and union them. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `myFunc` is a set-returning function, you can move it from the `FROM` part to the `SELECT` part, while referencing each member of the set returning record type that you want.

```
SELECT the_table_with_geom.some_primary_key,
       (myFunc(geom)).val1, (myFunc(geom)).val2
FROM the_table_with_geom;
```